# Uso de área proporcional com GridLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou tendo a seguinte dificuldade, depois de procurar exaustivamente no Google e não achar uma respostas para essa minha duvida, resolvi perguntar aqui, gostaria de colocar um TextView ao lado de um Button, de forma que o TextView utilize 2/3 da area útil e o Button o outro terço restante.

Atualmente o código está assim:

```
<GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:columnCount="3"
        >

        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Não possui uma conta?"
            android:background="#000"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:gravity="start|center" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="CADASTRE-SE"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#d69312"
            android:gravity="center" />

</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize um *LinearLayout* e recorra ao atributo `android:layout_weight` para definir, proporcionalmente, o espaço que cada *View* ocupa, depois atribua esse *layout* à coluna zero da sua *grid* indicando um *span* de 3

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:columnCount="3"
        >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_column="0">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Não possui uma conta?"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
                android:layout_weight="2"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#d69312"
                android:text="CADASTRE-SE"
                android:textStyle="bold" 
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

A soma dos valores indicados no atributo `android:layout_weight` corresponde a 100% do espaço total. No caso presente 100% corresponde a 3.

Assim, ao indicar `android:layout_weight="2"` no *TextView*, estamos a dizer que ele deve ocupar 2/3 do espaço.

Da mesma forma, ao indicar `android:layout_weight="1"` no *Button*, dizemos que o espaço a ocupar por ele deve ser 1/3 do espaço total.

**Nota:** A utilização do atributo `android:layout_weight` obriga que, de acordo com a orientação do *LinearLayout*, o `android:layout_width` ou `android:layout_height` seja definido com `"0dp"`.

**EDIT**

Apartir da API 21 o *Gridlayout* passa a ter o conceito de *weight*, assim, com o *xml* abaixo, consegue-se obter um resultado igual ao do *xml* anterior.

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:columnCount="2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:text="Não possui uma conta?"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="2"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:background="#d69312"
            android:text="CADASTRE-SE"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"/>

</GridLayout>
```